# how to remove a value from a list using remove() and setState() in Stateful widget in flutter using onpressed property of a button?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm trying to delete a quote from the list on clicking the button. but on click the list doesn't seem to be updated or the quote isn't being deleted on click.

any solutions would be appreciated !!!

this is a list of quotes which i'm displaying in a card in the activity

```
List<Quote> quotes =[
    Quote(quote: "be yourself; everyone else is already taken",author: "oscar wilde"),
    Quote(quote: "this is test quote 2",author: "mikey"),
    Quote(quote: "good thing about music, when it hits you, you feel no pain",author: "bob marley"),
  ];
```

using a textbutton to delete a particular quote on click

```
class QuoteCard extends StatelessWidget {
    
      final Quote quote;
      final Function delete;
      QuoteCard({required this.quote, required this.delete});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  quote.quote,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Text(
                  quote.author,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){ delete; },
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.delete),
                        Text(
                          'delete quote',
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

trying to delete the quote using the remove() method in setState()

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Awesome Quotes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((quote) => QuoteCard(
            quote:quote,
            delete:(){
                setState(() {
                  quotes.remove(quote);
                });
            }
        )).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `onPressed: delete,` not `onPressed: (){ delete; },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  quote.quote,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Text(
                  quote.author,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed:(){                 
                      delete();
                     },
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.delete),
                        Text(
                          'delete quote',
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Try this one, it works

```
onPressed:(){                
             delete();
            },
```

Comment: or even better: `onPressed: delete,` - no need for extra anonymous function

Comment: yeah i did try that for some reason it didn't work.